# absolute convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left(e - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

I have to check whether this alternating series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left(e - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)$ is convergent and *absolute* convergent. Using the Leibniz criteria I could show convergence. But I got stuck with the absolute convergence ...

I can show $\left|e - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right| \leq \frac{e}{n}$ but that would give a divergent upper bound. Anyway my guess is that it is not absolute convergent. But using $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$ and then $e - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \geq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ leads (I think) to a convergent lower bound.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well a Taylor expansion gives $|u_n|\sim\frac e{2n}$ so it is not absolutely convergent. How did you get $|e-(1+\frac 1n)^n|\le \frac en$ in the first place ? Maybe you can modify it to get the equivalent term with factor $\frac 12$.

Comment: You are so right: $ e - \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k} \geq \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left( \frac{n^k}{k!} - \binom{n}{k} \right) \frac{1}{n^k} \geq \left( \frac{n^2}{2!} - \binom{n}{2} \right) \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2n}$ and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that
\begin{align*}
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n & = \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {n\left( {\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{{2n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right)} \right)} \right) \\ & = e\exp \left( { - \frac{1}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right) = e - \frac{e}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right).
\end{align*}